# How do I hide elements in a given div based on an array of element types with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a page where the user can selectively remove certain elements and leave behind others.

The HTML I'm operating on is imported from elsewhere, so it's a little out of my control. I've wrapped it in a div with an id, and I want to be able to toggle on and off all the listed elements inside that div.

This is what I've got:

```
function toggle_elements() {
  var hide_elements=['blockquote','ul','dl','p','iframe'];
  $('#imported_content ' + hide_elements).toggle();
 };
```

While it "works," it's also toggling matching elements outside `#imported_content`. I'm a little confused, because I'd have expected that in failing the way it did, it would also just toggle `#imported_content` itself. But it's leaving the div alone and just toggling the elements specified in `hide_elements`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you're appending an entire array to the selector. Not sure if jQuery will automatically split them up so it works as expected. See my answer below and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little verbose and probably not the most efficient, but have you tried looping through your array and running `.toggle()` each iteration? See if the following works.

JS

```
function toggle_elements() {
  var hide_elements=['blockquote','ul','dl','p','iframe'];

  for (var i = 0; i < hide_elements.length; i++) {
    $('#imported_content').find(hide_elements[i]).toggle();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if the set of elements stay constant

```
...
var hide_elements=['blockquote','ul','dl','p','iframe'];
var jqo = $();

for (var i = 0; i < hide_elements.length; i++) {
  jqo.add($('#imported_content').find(hide_elements[i]));
}
...

function toggle_elements() {
  jqo.toggle()
};
```